# Printers that don't restrict activity on empty cartridge

Tags: printer

I'm interesting in knowing which brand of printers:

- print even if a cartridge color is empty
- don't put timestamp on the chipset of the cartridge to make them expire
- let you use the scanner even if there is an empty cartridge
- let you print in black and white even if the red cartridge is empty

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this question is valid - potentially subjective and argumentative - but I'm I a good mood atm so I've given it an edit, lets see what others think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canon pretty much tells you the cart is empty and continues printing even if its supposed to be empty with newer carts - the old models went "oh there's ink" and just printed - since the old models had nothing more than ink tanks - the newer ones have a chip that dosen't seem to have much of an effect.

Its also pretty easy to refill, and we tend to have carts last for the entire lifetime of the printer with third party ink. The most that happens when a canon MFD's ink is empty is you need to print faxes manually.

If you need to print black when colour is empty, many printers have a 'print black ink only' option that would help

AVOID dell and lexmark - they are impossible to refill apparently

Comment: Oh god, the ink tanks... I remember an *old* Epson one, it had no sensor/chip, it would somehow attempt to calculate the remaining ink in the cartridge by use. And it would not let you print until you replaced (read: reseated) the cartridges when they're supposed to be empty. Of course, at some point, it got out of alignment with actual ink levels and would stop printing when cartridges were still half full.